# Unity C# How to read Json data from a http server using JSON utility

Tags: c#, json, http, unity-game-engine

I really need to read the Json data from : 
https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/batch?types=quote,news,chart&range=1m&last=10

Unfortunately because I am a beginner I don't really understand the reference documentation about Json Utility. Can someone please help me passing the data from Json to c#.

Json data :

```
{
  "quote": {
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "companyName": "Apple Inc.",
    "primaryExchange": "Nasdaq Global Select",
    "sector": "Technology",
    "calculationPrice": "close",
    "open": 189.1,
    "openTime": 1526304600392,
    "close": 188.15,
    "closeTime": 1526328000294,
    "high": 189.53,
    "low": 187.86,
    "latestPrice": 188.15,
    "latestSource": "Close",
    "latestTime": "May 14, 2018",
    "latestUpdate": 1526328000294,
    "latestVolume": 15201663,
    "iexRealtimePrice": 188.17,
    "iexRealtimeSize": 100,
    "iexLastUpdated": 1526327999941,
    "delayedPrice": 188.15,
    "delayedPriceTime": 1526328000294,
    "previousClose": 188.59,
    "change": -0.44,
    "changePercent": -0.00233,
    "iexMarketPercent": 0.03066,
    "iexVolume": 466083,
    "avgTotalVolume": 34166845,
    "iexBidPrice": 0,
    "iexBidSize": 0,
    "iexAskPrice": 0,
    "iexAskSize": 0,
    "marketCap": 924783214700,
    "peRatio": 19.34,
    "week52High": 190.37,
    "week52Low": 142.2,
    "ytdChange": 0.10092655711038234
  }
}
```

I started writing some code to get the json string but i am not able to parse it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class DataManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string Index_name;
    public string URL;
    public string jsonString;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        URL = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/" + Index_name + "/batch?types=quote,news,chart&range=1m&last=10";      
    }

    public void Text_Changed(string newIndex)
    {
        Index_name = newIndex;
    }

    public void Request()
    {
        WWW request = new WWW(URL);
        StartCoroutine(OnResponse(request));
    }

    private IEnumerator OnResponse(WWW req)
    {
        yield return req;
        jsonString = req.text;    
    }
```

Comment: Paste json [here](http://json2csharp.com/) and generate the classes you need to de-serialize it. The duplicate should help you do the rest. If that's not working, edit your question with your new code. Before you do so, make sure to read the "troubleshooting" part of the answer from the duplicate.